компиляция проекта на c# в VS Code в один файл (standalong)
делаю свой первый проект на C# в VS Code.
в проекте использую стороннюю библиотеку.
сам проект состоит из одного файла.
нужно скомпилировать этот проект в один exe файл.
подскажите можно ли это сделать в VS Code и как?
поиск не помог. нашел только как это делается в Visual Studio (Как скомпилировать единый exe файл в проекте Visual Studio), но именно для VS Code ответов не нашел.
Update:
добавил в project file <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
использую команду dotnet publish -r win-x64
но все равно получаю набор файлов

Update:
добавил еще такой параметр в project file <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract> и все получилось, один файл на выходе.
спасибо за подсказки.

Single-file deployment - командами в консоли

@AlexanderPetrov, я впервые использую VS Code и не совсем понимаю куда мне это нужно вставить 'Add true to your project file.'

Файл с расширением .csproj
